# How to add some extra fields to the page in django-cms? (in django admin "add page form")

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

My question is almost identical to this one: [How to add some extra fields to the page in django-cms? (in django admin panel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293641/how-to-add-some-extra-fields-to-the-page-in-django-cms-in-django-admin-panel) but notice the "add page form".

I liked very much the Ben Davis's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15371900/1685973 but it does not add the custom field (named "color_scheme") in the "Add Page" admin form... That's what I would like to have :-).

(I would have added a comment instead of asking a new question if I could, but I do not have the required 50 points to do that)

Comment: I guess there should be an "else" to the "if obj:" in the CustomPageForm __init__, but I don't see an easy way to do that...

Comment: Are you looking to add fields to the admin page or models within the admin page? If your looking for extra fields in the admin page you could override the base.html admin template.